# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, datetime, python-datetime

I am new to python date and time types.

I have a date value.

```
date = '2018-11-10 10:55:31+00:00'
```

I need to check this date value is older than  90 days.

I tried :

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

past = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)
date = '2018-11-10 10:55:31+00:00'

if past > date :
   print("This is older than 90 days")
```

failing with the following error :
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'`

This might be because the date format for 'past' and the date value which I passed is different.

How  can I come up with this ?

Answer (score 16):

You have to use `strptime` to convert a string into a date.

The comparaison operator only applies between datetime.

```
date = datetime.strptime('2018-11-10 10:55:31', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

then can you do

```
if past > date :
   print("This is older than 90 days")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `dateutil` package and just convert your date string `date` to `datetime object and then check the condition with :

```
from dateutil import parser
past = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)
new_date = parser.parse("2018-11-10 10:55:31+00:00")
if past > new_date :
    print("This is older than 90 days")
```

that it : )

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your date string to `datetime`. You can do this in a couple of ways.

#### Use built-in `datetime.strptime`

For example, first convert to `datetime` before your comparison. This requires you to specify the format precisely ahead of time:

```
date = '2018-11-10 10:55:31+00:00'
date = datetime.strptime(date[:-6], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(date)

datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 10, 10, 55, 31)
```

#### Use a 3rd party library

One popular tool is [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse), which is able to parse most common datetime formats *without* the format specified in advance:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser

past = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)
date1 = '2018-11-10 10:55:31+00:00'
date2 = '2017-11-10 10:55:31+00:00'

for date in (date1, date2):
    if past > parser.parse(date[:-6]):
        print(f'This is older than 90 days: {date}')

This is older than 90 days: 2017-11-10 10:55:31+00:00
```