# How to read a JSON file hosted in git using flask API and return the value as a JSON output?

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to read a JSON file with has entries like this hosted on git

```
 {
    "time": "2021-01-29 10:30:00",
    "production_A": false,
    "production_B": false
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-01-29 10:50:00",
    "production_A": true,
    "production_B": true
  },
```

The input query would be of the form `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` eg start_time = "2021-01-28T07:30:00Z"end_time = "2021-01-28T13:30:00Z" . How to use flask to pass the time as a parameter in the format and return the required value which is the count of true values of each production in the given timelimit.

I wrote the given script to do this

```
import json,datetime

t1 = "2021-01-28T01:30:00Z"
t2 = "2021-01-29T10:10:00Z"
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
with open('sample.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        time = item.get('time')
        #timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        while time > t1 and time < t2:
            print(time)
```

but I get the following error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\titto\Desktop\test.py", line 12, in <module> while time > t1 and time < t2: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`

How to solve this ?

Comment: Well, and what is your problem? Get started with the first step and if you have problems you can't solve doing some research, ask here. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: How to access time stamp in json and compare it with another stamp, like iterate through the time stamps until a particular time. how to format this ?

Comment: Convert both time to milliseconds. And then do the comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248537/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-datetime-datetime-and-str)